# How to store current user information, security, and preferences

Tags: vb.net, winforms, security

I need a *Global* variable/class that stores some basic information about the currently logged in user including that user's preferences, security rights, UserID, etc.  This information will be needed by any/every part of my application.

In the past I have either used a Public variable/class in a vb.net module for this purpose.  I'm trying to get away from my old ways of doing things and was curious what people currently do for this functionality.

I am thinking a singleton or 2 regarding preferences and security but am not sure if that is the best way to go.

**EDIT:**  This is an n-Tier WinForms application.

Comment: standalone, client/server, n-tier web based? Depending on your deployment architecture, singletons have now almost become an antipattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my ASP .net web app, I store an object that contains login information for that user in the Session Cache.  That is one way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different "global variables" for each user, then sessions are the way to go (as Russell mentioned). If you want variables that are the same for every single user, then Application variables are what you want.